# SIFR and HTML entities

Tags: html, sifr

I have a webpage with an 'o' with an acute. How would I get this entity to display in sIFR3?
I have output the html as both ó and ó

Many thanks,
C

Comment: @clint: do you still need more info in order to accept an answer? Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [doc](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/How+to+use):

> Special characters
>
> If you want to use special characters
>   in your text; characters like » or
>   special language characters that are
>   not in font by default you must add it
>   in Flash before publishing it to SWF.
>   Open the hidden text box. Select it
>   and click the Character button in the
>   Properties pallette. Add the special
>   characters in the textbox at the
>   bottom of the dialog box.